Is the product of the modulus of the largest entry in an invertible matrix and the modulus of the largest entry in its inverse at least 1?
Let $A$ be an invertible matrix with complex entries. Is it true that $$\left(\max_{i,j} |A_{ij}|\right)\left( \max_{i,j} |(A^{-1})_{ij}|\right) \geq 1,$$
where $(A^{-1})_{ij}$ is the $ij$th entry in $A^{-1}$?
Equality holds when the given matrix is diagonal, and any upper triangular matrix with all 1's on and above the diagonal demonstrates that the conjectured inequality can be strict. I haven't been able to come up with an example that contradicts this inequality, but I also cannot deduce it.
My observations so far are the following:

Use Cramer's rule and a cofactor expansion of the resulting $\det A$ factor that pops out to put the expresion in terms of only the entries in $A$ and the adjugate of $A$.

The quantity in question is also invariant under scaling, so we could assume without loss of generality that, say, $\max_{i,j} |a_{ij}|=1$.

I have also tried to prove this inequality by using matrix norms, but my attempt didn't yield anything substantial.


Any help or a potential reference would be appreciated.

So, you don't mean $a_{ij}^{-1}=(a_{ij})^{-1}?$ That's confusing notation. Better to use $A_{ij}$ and $(A^{-1})_{ij}.$

That's a good suggestion. I originally was using $||A||_\infty$ to denote the max, but that LaTeX wasn't displaying correctly.

The comment and answer shows that the conjecture is false, but we could also ask what is the smallest $\left(\max_{i,j} |A_{ij}|\right)\left( \max_{i,j}
| (A^{-1})_{ij}|\right)$ can be.

We can get a lower bound using determinants - note that if $a = \max_{i,j} |A_{ij}|$ and $b = \max_{i,j} |(A^{-1}){ij}|$ then $|\det(A)| = |\sum{\sigma \in S_n} (-1)^{\operatorname{sgn} \sigma} \prod_{i=1}^n A_{i \sigma(i)}| \leq n! a^n$ if $A$ is $n\times n$, and similarly for $A^{-1}$, and so $1 = |\det(A) \det(A^{-1})| \leq n!^2 a^n b^n$ gives $ab \geq (1/n!^2)^{1/n}$. But I have no idea how close this is to sharp.

Looking into this a bit more, it turns out this more general question is intimately connected with the theory of Hadamard matrices, with Hadamard's inequality giving the bound $ab \geq 1/n$, and Hadamard matrices showing that this is sharp, at least for $n$ where Hadamard matrices can be constructed. The question of for which $n$ Hadamard matrices exist is open, and so I think the question of minimizing $\left(\max_{i,j} |A_{ij}|\right)\left( \max_{i,j} |(A^{-1})_{ij}|\right)$ is likely open as well.

Counterexample:
$$
A=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\pmatrix{1&-1\\ 1&1},\quad A^{-1}=A^T,
\quad \left(\max_{i,j} |A_{ij}|\right)\left( \max_{i,j} |(A^{-1})_{ij}|\right)=\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2<1.
$$
